# Soap webservice in Nodejs throws "Can't set headers after they are sent." error

Tags: node.js

Nodejs code:

```
router.post('/getdata', function(req, res) {
   xmlhttp.open('POST', webserviceurl, true);

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          var xmlString = xmlhttp.responseText;

          parser.parseString(xmlString, function(err, xmlresult){
            if(err) throw err
            res.send({result:xmlresult}); 
          });   
        }
     }  //return false;
   }
   // Send the POST request

   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
   xmlhttp.send(args);
});
```

Jquery code:

```
function getWebservicedata(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {id:userid},
      url: '/getdata',
      dataType: 'JSON'
    }).done(function( data ) {
       console.log(data)
    });

}
```

While sending the result from node.js to Ajax, it will throw `Can't set headers after they are sent` error as XML request uses one send() function and node.js uses one more `send()` function.

`Send()` function is conflicting and throws the error.

Comment: res.send() does .end() so the response has already been closed. What your looking for is res.write() i believe. This does not call .end()

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: But res.write()  won't send the xml result back to ajax function. How we can do that .. any idea?